# Reverse "Guess the Number" program

Tags: c++, number-guessing-game

I recently got to a certain exercise in a book I am reading, and am looking for feedback. It is a program in which the user picks a number and the computer uses algorithms to guess it. If there is any way that I can improve my code, feedback is really appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0))); //seed random number generator
    int compNumber = rand() % 100 + 1;

    int yourNumber;
    cout << "Please input a number between 1 and 100" << endl;
    cin >> yourNumber;

    cout << "Ok! I'm gonna try to guess it!" << endl;

    while (compNumber != yourNumber)
    {
        if (compNumber > yourNumber)
        {
            do
            {
                --compNumber;
            } while (compNumber != yourNumber);
        }

        else if (compNumber > yourNumber)
        {
            do
            {
                ++compNumber;
            } while (compNumber != yourNumber);
        }

    }

    cout << "I guessed it! Your number is " << compNumber << endl;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Good job on your first question.

Comment: I guess maybe I don't understand - what is the point of the loops? They're just a very indirect way of writing `compNumber = yourNumber;`?

Comment: Barry, it really is just that. In my mind by giving it a complex algorithm the computer would be "guessing" the number I inputted, but it really is a glorified 'compNumber = yourNumber' statement. I am currently in the process of reworking the code!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure this generates a random number from 1 -> 100.

```
int compNumber = rand() % 100 + 1;
```

**BUT** not all the numbers have an even probability. Assuming RAND_MAX is 32768 (a common value). Then the number 1->68 have a slightly higher probability than the number 69->100.

To get an even distribution you need to compensate for this:

```
int compNumber
do
{
    compNumber = rand();
}
while (compNumber > (RAND_MAX / 100 * 100));
compNumber = compNumber % 100 + 1;
```

Better yet learn to use the modern random number generator that is built into C++.

```
// I have not tested this.
// Just copied and pasted from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19666713/14065
// This is the modern equivalent of srand()
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 mt(rd());
std::uniform_real_distribution<int> dist(1, 100);


// Then usage is.
// equivalent of rand().
std::cout << dist(mt) << "\n";
```

This does not look correct:

```
    if      (compNumber > yourNumber)
    {}
    else if (compNumber > yourNumber)
    {}
```

The conditions look the same to me.

This does not look like guessing.

```
        do
        {
            --compNumber;
        } while (compNumber != yourNumber);
```

This looks like the computer counting down until it reaches your number.

Comment: Note modern random number generator requires a `C++11` compiler.

Comment: To be more precise, point about `rand() % N` matters as `N` approaches `RAND_MAX`. If we compare probabilities of generating 2 numbers - one from higher part and one from lower, the latter would be around `1 + N / RAND_MAX` of the former, which translates to about 0.3% difference in our particular case, but gets to around 1/3 if `N` is 10000.

Answer (score 7):

Based on your (vague) description of the exercise, it seems like the user should keep the number in their head until the very end, and each time the computer guesses a number the user tells the computer if the number is higher or lower. That's the exact reverse of the usual programming exercise. In that case, what you could do is:

```
int compNumber = 50;
int low = 1;
int high = 100;
int yourNumber;
do
{
    yourNumber=0;
    cout << "Please input a number between 1 and 100" << endl;
    cin >> yourNumber;
} while(yourNumber<1||yourNumber>100);   /* a check to make sure the number is actually between 1 and 100 */

while(compNumber!=yourNumber)
{
    if(yourNumber<compNumber)
    {
        cout << "I guessed " << compNumber << " (too low)" << end1;
        high = compNumber;
        compNumber=(compNumber+low-1)/2;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "I guessed " << compNumber << " (too high)" << end1;
        low = compNumber;
        compNumber=(compNumber+high+1)/2;
    }
}
cout << "I guessed it! Your number is " << compNumber << end1;
```

Answer (score 1):

If i'm correct, the answer that Blue gave is entirely correct.
Although i have one minor improvement.
Using his code actually makes the computer guess your number but it always starts guessing at 50. If you would like the computer to start at a different number each time you can add the line:

```
srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));
```

and change the line after that too:

```
int compNumber = rand() % 100+1;
```

This will only change the starting number, so that the computer will start at a different number each times, either enlarging the chances of the computer guessing the number or making them smaller.
this would be the entire code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));
    int compNumber = rand() % 100+1;
    int low = 1;
    int high = 100;
    int yourNumber;
    do
    {
        yourNumber = 0;
        cout << "Please input a number between 1 and 100" << endl;
        cin >> yourNumber;
    } while (yourNumber < 1 || yourNumber>100);   /* a check to make sure the number is actually between 1 and 100 */

    while (compNumber != yourNumber)
    {
        if (yourNumber < compNumber)
        {
            cout << "I guessed " << compNumber << " (too high)" << endl;
            high = compNumber;
            compNumber = (compNumber + low - 1) / 2;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "I guessed " << compNumber << " (too low)" << endl;
            low = compNumber;
            compNumber = (compNumber + high + 1) / 2;
        }
    }
    cout << "I guessed it! Your number is " << compNumber << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

You could even show after the guesses how many tries it took the computer to guess the number. Just add the variable: `int guesses = 0;` and directly after:

> ```
> compNumber = (compNumber + low - 1) / 2;
> ```

put

```
 ++guesses;
```

and after:

> ```
> cout << "I guessed it! Your number is " << compNumber << endl;
> ```

you could put:

```
cout << "Number of guesses it took me: " << guess << endl;
```

now it will show how many guesses it took the computer to guess it

Comment: Thanks for editing my comment @rolfl, it was the first comment I made and I'm quite sure I made some mistakes. I'm new to C++ and am quite eager to learn a lot about it!